Could there be no current through a wire with a difference in voltage?
So I made this circuit on a simulator to help with my physics problem at school. As you can see from the picture, there is a voltage difference of 5V between B and D.
I know that the voltage difference between $B$ and $D$ is equal to the electromotive force of the 5V battery, as $E = U_{BD} + I_{BD}*r$, with r being the internal resistance of the battery. And since $I_{BD}$ is 0, I get $U_{BD} = E$.
However, I'm confused about why there is no current flowing through BD if there is a difference in voltage there, since electric current appear when there is a difference in voltage between two point.
Please explain it to me. Thanks


What exactly is  between the negative terminal of the battery and point D?

If you were measuring voltage on terminals of a 5V battery, would you think there has to be non-zero current flowing through it? If yes, how large a current would you expect?

The wire you are measuring current through has no voltage across it.  You are measuring across not just a wire, but a wire in series with a voltage source.  The voltage you read is exactly the voltage across the voltage source.  The voltage source does not need to supply any current to maintain exactly 5V.

Let the currents run in anticlockwise direction. Top current is $i_1$ bottom left is $i_2$ bottom right is $i_3$.
Then you can get three simultaneous equations:
$$7i_1-i_2-4i_3=16$$
$$-i_1+8i_2+0i_3=5$$
$$-4i_1+0i_2+7i_3=-5$$
If you solve these you find $$i_1=3, i_2=1, i_3=1$$
But as $i_2$ and $i_3$ are equal but in opposite directions, the total current between B and D is zero.
(As for the voltage reading, if you remove everything from the circuit except the 5V battery, what would be the voltage between B and D? 5V. You are just reading the voltage across the battery.)

+1 Thanks for catching my mistake.
